# Upnp browse mediatomb content inside vlc?

Tags: nas, vlc-media-player, streaming

Hey guys, I have a nice NAS box up running samba.  The problem I'm running into is that my wireless network isn't fast enough to stream the blue ray rips I have, and I don't want to waste space saving both the original rip, and a low res one (for wireless).

I found mediatomb (a live transcoder with upnp support) and wanted to use it to stream to vlc player.  If I copy the direct stream link from mediatomb and paste it into vlc it works fine, but I want to be able to browse my content inside vlc (like the playlists). 
 My upnp server doesn't show up anywhere I've looked in vlc (including playlists, etc).

Any thoughts?
Thanks, Max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instructions

```
Ubuntu Linux Distribution
    1. Open a command line terminal and type “sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/vlc” and press “Enter.”
    2. Type “sudo apt-get update” on the command line and press “Enter.”
    3. Type “sudo apt-get install vlc vlc-plugin-pulse mozilla-plugin-vlc“ at the command prompt and press “Enter.”
    4. Click “Applications” in the desktop dock. Click “Video & Sound,” and then “VLC.”
    5. Click the “Tools” menu near the top of the “VLC Media Player” window. Click “Preferences.”
    6. Click the “All” radio button. Click the + next to “Playlist.” Click the + next to “Services discovery.”
    7. Click the “Universal Plug and Play (UPNP)” check box and click “Save.”
    8. Click the “View” menu and click “Playlist.” Click “Local Network” and click “Universal Plug and Play.”
Fedora Linux Distribution
    9. Open a command line terminal and type “su –“ and tap “Enter.” Type the root password if prompted and press “Enter.”
    10. Type “rpm -ivh http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-stable.noarch.rpm” at the command prompt and tap “Enter.” Write “yum install vlc” on the command line and press “Enter.”
    11. Enter “yum install mozilla-vlc” on the command line and press “Enter.” Type “vlc --services-discovery upnp_intel” on the command line and tap “Enter.”
    12. Click the “Tools” menu item and then “Preferences.” Click “All” in the lower left pane. Click + next to “Playlist” and then click + beside “Services discovery.”
    13. Click to select the “Universal Plug and Play (UPNP)” box and click “Save.”
Mandriva Linux Distribution
    14. Open a command line terminal. Type “urpmi libdvdplay0 wxvlc vlc-plugin-a52 vlc-plugin-ogg vlc-plugin-mad libmatroska0” at the command prompt and press “Enter.”
    15. Enter “urpmi libdvdcss2” on the command line and press “Enter.”
    16. Type “vlc --services-discovery upnp_intel” at the command prompt and press “Enter.”
    17. Click the “Tools” menu and “Preferences.” Click the “All” radio button. Click + next to “Playlist” and then + next to “Services discovery.”
    18. Click the “Universal Plug and Play (UPNP)” check box and click “Save.”
```

Blatantly copied from here (in case the link dies): How to Connect VLC to UPNP Server | eHow.com http://www.ehow.com/how_12074436_connect-vlc-upnp-server.html